# SQL: Unique index for two columns where value of one is NOT DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `group_owner` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

With `group_owner` acting as a `boolean`, I am trying to make a unique index to where any given group ID can only have one row where `group_owner = 1`.

Something like:

```
UNIQUE KEY (`group_id`,`group_owner`) ... WHERE group_owner NOT DEFAULT
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I would probably just handle the logic in the INSERT itself, but perhaps someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong structure for your data.  What you need is a `groups` table.  And that should have the foreign key reference:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  user_id varchar(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id varchar(36) NOT NULL
);

create table groups (
    group_id int auto_increment primary key,
    group_name varchar(36) not null,
    owner_user_id varchar(36),
    constraint fk_groups_owner foreign key (owner_user_id) references users (user_id)
);

alter table users add constraint fk_users_groups
    foreign key (group_id) references groups(group_id);
```

Voila!  Only one owner per group.

Notes:

- I made `group_id` an integer.  I find that auto-incremented values are better for primary keys.  I would recommend doing the same for `users` as well.
- This allows a user to be in only one group.
- In practice, you will insert a group with a `NULL` owner.  Then insert the user with the appropriate group, and then set the owner to the user.

Actually, the above data model runs the risk that a user could be the owner of a group s/he is not a member of.  That is fixed with a slight tweak:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  user_id varchar(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (group_id, user_id)
);

create table groups (
    group_id int auto_increment primary key,
    group_name varchar(36) not null,
    owner_user_id varchar(36),
    constraint fk_groups_owner foreign key (group_id, owner_user_id) references users (group_id, user_id)
);

alter table users add constraint fk_users_groups
    foreign key (group_id) references groups(group_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's the structure I was originally trying to go with, but then I was running into problems with building a constraint to `...  ON DELETE CASCADE` to delete the group when the group owner is deleted. If you could please help with that I would very greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Also, if the users table requires a valid group and the group table requires a valid user, how do you insert records?

Comment: @MultiDev . . . That is not part of your question but cascading foreign key constraints work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8968c515843bf0dc4be9d94cfea680b.